# How to build list of entity in RESTful response

Tags: rest, api, jax-rs, restful-url

```
@GET
@Path("/books")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response allBooks() {

// Given a list of books
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

books.add(new Book("1190","Mind Your Steps"));
books.add(new Book("2287","Look Up"));

GenericEntity entity = new GenericEntity<List<Book>>(books){};

return Response.ok(entity).build();
//return Response.ok().entity(entity).build();
}
```

Trying to build a list while response, but i am not getting the result. It's showing "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request." Please help me.

Or should i need to follow some other approach for return multiple rows in RESTful API response

Comment: `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ` you should stick to one.

Comment: hmm.. are you sure? I want to be compatible with both XML and JSON..

Comment: My mistake, you can it seems :P

Comment: Are you using XML or JSON? Can you show the Book class? Can you show your project dependencies? Is there any stack trace in the server log (if so, so show it). Please answer answer all these questions and edit your post with the answers. Thanks.